# Publicar aplicación web con Docker y SSL (Con certificados autofirmados)

Tags: asp.net, docker

Saludos,

Actualmente estoy desarrollando una pequeña aplicación con AspNetCore que deseo desplegar en Linux con Docker.

Hasta el momento todo funciona perfectamente; sin embargo, tengo un requerimiento que no he podido implementar: Necesito que la aplicación se acceda por https (Por el momento con un certificado autorifmado -  es un ambiente de pruebas).

Para poner a correr la aplicación simplemente ejecuto en el linux (CentOS 6.8) docker run -p 80:80 {container-id} y esto deja disponible la aplicación corriendo en el puerto 80.

La duda que tengo, y que he estado investigando pero no encuentro mucha info... es como puedo hacer para que la aplicación funcione sobre https, asumo que debe ser más que run -p 80:443 ya que necesito que el https incluya el certificado ssl que ya tengo generado.

La otra opción que habia pensado es un proxy reverso... pero no se si sea mucho esfuerzo para tan poco...

Agradezco sus comentarios.

Comment: Ejecutas sobre Apache o NGINX? Kestrel?

Comment: Por ahora estoy utilizando Kestrel para AspNetCore. No me gustaría tener que utilizar NGINX para hacer un proxy reverso. ¿Existirá otra alternativa?.

Comment: En vez de utilizar nginx como reverse proxy tenés el HaProxy. [Aquí](https://serversforhackers.com/using-ssl-certificates-with-haproxy) explican como utilizarlo con SSL.